# Navigation bar button is not clickable

Tags: objective-c, ios

I add this navigation bar code but i am not able to click on the left side lat item button "Edit" and when i replace with textbox even that is also not work (not take value), if you can figure that out what is the wrong with this code i will be very help full to you.

Thanks,

Aashish

find the screen shot
http://www.flickr.com/photos/71234685@N02/6440926473/in/photostream

```
-(void) initializeNavigationalBar {

UIToolbar* _leftNavBarTools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44.01)];

// create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar

NSMutableArray* _leftNavBarButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

UIBarButtonItem* _editScenarioProduct = self.editButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem* _addTurftype = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Turftype" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(getTurfType)];

UIBarButtonItem *_addTargetN = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Target N" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(getTargetNperWeek)];

UIBarButtonItem *_addMapRegion = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Map Region" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(getMapRegion)];

CGRect _textFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 30 );
_turfacresTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:_textFrame];
_turfacresTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
_turfacresTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
_turfacresTextField.placeholder = @"Turf Acres";
_turfacresTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
_turfacresTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
_turfacresTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
_turfacresTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
_turfacresTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

UIBarButtonItem *_addTurfacres = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_turfacresTextField]; 

[_leftNavBarButtons addObject:_addTurftype];
[_leftNavBarButtons addObject:_addTargetN];
[_leftNavBarButtons addObject:_addMapRegion];
[_leftNavBarButtons addObject:_addTurfacres];
[_leftNavBarButtons addObject:_editScenarioProduct];

[_leftNavBarTools setItems:_leftNavBarButtons animated:NO];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_leftNavBarTools];

UIToolbar* _rightNavBarTools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44.01)];

// create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
NSMutableArray* _rightNavBarButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

UIBarButtonItem *_addSoilSetting = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(setSoilandCarryover)];
[_rightNavBarButtons addObject:_addSoilSetting];

 UIBarButtonItem* _addApplication = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Appplication" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(addApplication)];

[_rightNavBarButtons addObject:_addApplication];

[_rightNavBarTools setItems:_rightNavBarButtons animated:NO];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_rightNavBarTools];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [self editButtonItem] instead of self.editButtonItem.

Comment: Thanks, but after posting my question i caught problem that was size of toolbar is small then the added size of button.